# android.support.v7.widget.Recyclerview could not be initiated error in eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I imported Recyclerview from sdk support library in eclipse and import this library to my project. Instead of this xml file of my project gives the error of "android.support.v7.widget.Recyclerview could not be initiated" error in eclipse.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your target sdk version and the version of RecyclerView library are the same.

Comment: I check by set both target sdk same,but it shows same error message

Comment: Does it show this message also when you build or is it just a preview issue?

Comment: Thanks, I check recyclerview with add items using Recyclerview.adapter and it's build successfully,it's just a preview issue.....can you tell me why this preview message display on add recyclerview?

Comment: It need to build the project at least once usually to be able to display. So after you built it might be ok. Or it's just in general a preview renderer issue you have. As long as it build... all is peachy :-)

Comment: I don't use eclipse anymore, in android studio once you run build project once, the preview for recycler view is fine after adding the library